# loading previous input values with local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, local-storage

I am creating a "Mad Libs" function and I want to utilize local storage along with it.

If the user has entered values into the input fields, I want those values saved in localStorage... and then when the page is reloaded, those values are loaded into the story that's generated once the page loads.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// input references
var animalRef = document.getElementById("animal");
var nameRef = document.getElementById("name");

// local storage for each input
localStorage["animal"] = animalRef.value;
localStorage["name"] = nameRef.value;

// generate story with user inputs
var generateRef = document.getElementById("generate");
generateRef.addEventListener("click", generateStory);

function generateStory(event){
    var storyRef = document.getElementById("story");

    storyRef.innerHTML = "Once Upon a Time, there was an {{animal}} named {{name}} . . .";

    storyRef.innerHTML = storyRef.innerHTML.replace("{{animal}}", animalRef.value);
    storyRef.innerHTML = storyRef.innerHTML.replace("{{name}}", nameRef.value);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="madLibs">
    <!-- user inputs /-->
    <b>Animal</b><br/>
    <input id="animal" placeholder="animal"/><br/>
    <b>Name</b><br/>
    <input id="name" placeholder="name"/><br/>

    <!-- button /-->
    <p align="center"><input id="generate" type="button" value="generate story"/></p>

    <hr/>

    <!-- output story /-->
    <div id="story"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

save localstorage on pageleave

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    localStorage.setItem("animal") = animalRef.value;
    localStorage.setItem("name")   = nameRef.value;
}
```

check for keys on pageload

```
if(localStorage.getItem("animal") != null) {
    storyRef.innerHTML = storyRef.innerHTML.replace("{{animal}}", localStorage.getItem("animal"));
}
if(localStorage.getItem("name") != null) {
    storyRef.innerHTML = storyRef.innerHTML.replace("{{animal}}", localStorage.getItem("name"));
}
```